# Finding the last updated file in shell, Excluding directory

Tags: shell, automation

hie, 
i am new to shell. on searching in StackOverflow I found a code which finds the last updated file in a directory including subdirectory.

`find $path -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2 | tail -n`

my requirement is to find the last updated file in the directory but not subdirectory

the directory has files in CSV format and 3-subdirectories, is there any way to modify this existing code? or search using CSV tag so that it only checks the CSV file, not the Subdirectory(subdirectory also contains .csv files).

Thanks

Comment: A simple technique is `ls -t` to list files sorted by timestamp. Do `ls -lt *.csv` to show the timestamps and limit the list to CSV files. You can also use `find` with args that limit it to CSV files via `-iname *.csv` and I think you can limit its depth.

Answer (score 1):

Use **find** command with **maxdepth 1** argument, it will not search for subdirectory.
Then you can use **-exec** to add command which will run for matched files.
Finally use **tail -1** to get the latest file name, and **basename** to extract file name from full path.

Here's an example,

```
basename $(find $Path -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -exec ls -t {} \;  | tail -1)
```